# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'

Tags: c#

I was watching tutorials on youtube to make my unity character moving but I'm stuck at the movement. I checked comments to see if anyone has the same problem I didn't see anyone with same problem but I get this error:

> Assets\PlayerMov.cs(15,24): error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMov : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
  
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move =(transform.right * x * transform.forward * z);

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: The middle `*` on that line is probably a typo for `+`.

Comment: `Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;`

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports only [multiplication of `Vector3` by a number](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_multiply.html). But you can [add](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html) two vectors or [subtract](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_subtract.html) one from another.